# Query Perfornance for querying XML Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

We are thinking of providing some advanced querying capabilities to application.

The application is in Retail domain and storing the core Entities in XML Column for all the main entities(Invoice, Order, Product etc) in the application.

The database is already > 10GB in size.

Will it be good choice to use query against XML Column in SQL Server, what are alternative to these as the core entity data is always stored as XML instead of RDBMS tables.

Comment: I wonder what you except by asking that question? With so few performance indicators you can't really expect us to provide feedback that this is a good or bad idea. This question is seriously undermined. It is similar to asking "What is bad about owning an Porsche 911 and what are the performance implication".

Comment: @dirkk tried to re-frame the question.  Indeed i do have problem. At this moment i am thinking was the design decision to store the core entity data as XML column was the evil decision as this is slowing the querying capabilities of system.

Comment: The question is still not really useful. If you want to store XML in your RDBMS you should of course do it in an XML column. Of course you could somehow split it up and store atomic values, but this all depends on your concrete data and usage, which you do not show us. XML data types in RDBMS are usually indexable, so if you have performance issues make sure you do use them. As always in database design, using indexes is key.